# ActiveX Multiselect Listbox working for one excel workbook but not working in another workbook

Tags: excel, excel-2013, vba

I had created a activex multiselect listbox in one excel workbook in my machine. It was not working. On deleting MSForms.exd, it started working again. However, another excel workbook with the same piece of code for activex multiselect listbox is not working in my machine.

Answer (score 0):

Same solution; restart your computer and before opening any office apps search out MSforms.exd *again* and delete all instances. this is apparently not a "once and for all" solution, I guess we're still waiting Microsoft's solution to their update 'faux pas.'